# phalcon framework webtools not working when creating models, views and controllers

Tags: php, windows, phalcon

I'm having some problems while trying to get phalcon webtools working.

When using command line devtools I can create controllers and models without problems.

However, things aren't that easy with the webtools.

It correctly shows already created controllers and models:

- Controllers (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQQ2s.png)
- Models (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIEZF.png)

And I can also edit them (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycKly.png).

Apparently, Db connexion is ok, since webtools shows every table in the DB:

- Models (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sALO.png)
- Scaffolding (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb4ho.png)

However, when trying to create a controller from the web interface, I got the next error:

> "Please specify a controller directory"

Same when trying to create a Model from a database table :

> "Database configuration cannot be loaded from your config file"

Or when trying to generate scaffold :

> "Adapter was not found in the config. Please specify a config variable
>   [database][adapter]"

My app/config/config.php content:

```
return new \Phalcon\Config(array(
    'database' => array(
        'adapter'     => 'Mysql',
        'host'        => 'localhost',
        'username'    => 'phalcon',
        'password'    => 'phalcon',
        'dbname'      => 'phalcon',
        'charset'     => 'utf8',
    ),
    'application' => array(   
        'controllersDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/controllers/',
        'modelsDir'      => __DIR__ . '/../../app/models/',
        'viewsDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/views/',
        'pluginsDir'     => __DIR__ . '/../../app/plugins/',
        'libraryDir'     => __DIR__ . '/../../app/library/',
        'cacheDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/cache/',
        'baseUri'        => '/phalconTest/',

    )
));
```

My public/webtools.config.php content:

```
define('PTOOLS_IP', '192.168.248.135');
define('PTOOLSPATH', 'C:/phalcon-devtools');
```

My public/webtools.php:

```
use Phalcon\Web\Tools;
require 'webtools.config.php';
require PTOOLSPATH . '/scripts/Phalcon/Web/Tools.php';

Tools::main(PTOOLSPATH, PTOOLS_IP);
```

Im running **Phalcon 1.3.4 - Windows x86 for PHP 5.4.0 (VC9)**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug in webtools.

Look at `vendor/phalcon/devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Builder/Component.php`
there is the `_getConfig` function.

The quick and dirty solution is prepend `../` to `path`.

Comment: First off, thanks for your answer. I did so and now controller generations works ! Sadly, it stills fails when trying to create models ("Database configuration cannot be loaded from your config file") or with scaffolding ("Builder doesn't knows where is the models directory" and "Undefined index: modelsNamespace in C:\phalcon-devtools\scripts\Phalcon\Builder\Scaffold.php ").

Comment: While trying to create a model it also says both PTOOLS_IP and PTOOLSPATH  are already defined

Comment: @MiGU I've found it, for model's you need '/../app/config/' yet for scaffold you need '../app/config/' So you have to change it after making models so you can make scaffolding. Can't understand why though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the first line in `app/config/config.php`

`defined('APP_PATH') || define('APP_PATH', realpath('..'));`

Answer (score 0):

To add to some of the answers, the editing of configPath by prepending ../ and also some code changes, has forgotten a a little '/' when modelPath has been rtrimmed.

Also, code will be updated and fixed but as of now, one can probably fix the issues by editing `your/path/phalcon-devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Builder/Model.php`; find

```
$modelsDir = rtrim(rtrim($modelsDir, '/'), '\\') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if ($this->isAbsolutePath($modelsDir) == false) {
        $modelPath = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $modelsDir;
    } else {
      //  $modelPath = $modelsDir;
    // replace or ADD TO LINE ABOVE so it looks like BELOW:
          $modelPath = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $modelsDir;
}
```

Then Models will work in webtools along with [TKF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28507335). Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Apply changes in webtools.config.php like here:

```
<?php

if (!defined('PTOOLS_IP'))
    define('PTOOLS_IP', '192.168.');

if (!defined('PTOOLSPATH'))
    define('PTOOLSPATH', '/path/to/phalcon/devtools');

return array(
    'application' => array(   
        'controllersDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/controllers/',
        'modelsDir'      => __DIR__ . '/../../app/models/',
    ),
    'database' => array(
        'adapter' => 'Mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'usr',
        'password' => 'pwd',
        'dbname' => 'dbname',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related, I had an issue with the webtools url getting longer and longer .. Eventually I could fix this by adding the word `webtools` in a replacement for the `baseUri` in `config.php` .

```
<?php ### config.php ... somewhat relevant parts ...
return new \Phalcon\Config([
    'database' => [ # ... some things ...
    ],
    'application' => [ # ... some more ...
        // This allows the baseUri to be understand project paths that are not in the root directory
        // of the webpspace.  This will break if the public/index.php entry point is moved or
        // possibly if the web server rewrite rules are changed. This can also be set to a static path.
        'baseUri'        => preg_replace(
            '/(public([\/\\\\]))?(index)|(webtools).php$/',
            '',
            $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
        ),
    ]
]);
```